# accessing local variables within a method of different class in main class

Tags: java

Need some help in resolving ambiguity wrt to local variables.

I have a java package with 2 class including main.
So one main + class1. I have a method in class1 which capture some data in local String objects within the method.
I want to use these local string objects in the Main class.
Is there a way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there are. Unfortunately, there are lots of them, so you need to be a lot more specific about the structure of your classes, as well as "capturing" and "using" that `String` variable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Hmmm, good point, I may have been too narrow below.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use these local string objects in the Main class. Is there a way to do this.

The appropriate way to do that is usually to pass them into a method of your Main class as arguments. Or alternately, pass them as arguments into a constructor of your Main class, if it is relevant to the state of a Main instance.